# Create UnitTest option grayed out

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio

I just discovered the sql server data tool which allows unit testing of database procedures, functions etc within Visual Studio 2012.

The problem is I haven't been able to get it to work. I've created a database project, imported my database but when I right click on a stored procedure, the 'Create Unit Test' option is greyed out. Apparently the issue may occur if your database has errors? In my case, I know there are some stored procedures broken, but they won't be fixed at this point in this time. Unless if the issue is related to that, they won't be fixed at this moment.

Comment: Same here! in my case, the project builds, latest SSDTs are installed, but no Sql Server Unit Test project is in the new project template list, Create Unit Test is grayed out.

Comment: Thanks. I actually got it working. Basically I had to resolve all the errors before the option was made available. Of one of the main issues was that I had to add database references.

Comment: ah ha! that was it - I only had a "differ only by case" warning and that disabled the Create Unit Test... geez. thanks.

Comment: How do you add a database reference?